# Android socket connects but cant write to it

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I was trying to get some networking going in my app, but i encountered some issues. It seems that I cant write to the OutputStream object. Though my server recieves the connection, it does not recieve any data. I've tried using Writer, DataOutputStream among others. none seemed to work.
My app uses asynctasks that call this object with a Socket object and a message. (The socket object has already been used to set Streams after initialisation using the setStreams method.)
can someone please try and find the problem? I will be very thankful.

```
public class NetworkingUtils {
private OutputStream out = null;
private InputStream in = null;

//set streams
public void setStreams(Socket sock){
    if (sock.isConnected()) {
        try {
            this.out = (OutputStream) sock.getOutputStream();
            this.in = (InputStream) sock.getInputStream();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Log.d("SOCKET", "FAILED TO SET STREAMS");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//send \n terminated messages to pre defined socket
public void sendMessage(Socket sock, String message) throws Throwable {
    if (sock.isConnected()) {
        try {
            this.out.write(message.getBytes());
            Log.d("SOCKET","WRITING COMPLETE. " + message);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

public String recvMessage(Socket sock) throws Throwable {
    //receives \n terminated message from pre defined socket
    String answer = null;
    if (sock.isConnected()){
        try{
            answer = this.convertStreamToString(this.in);
            Log.d("SOCKET","READING COMPLETE");
        }
        catch (Throwable e){
            Log.d("socket",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.d("socket","is not connected!!!");
    }
    if (answer.length() == 0){
        //empty string answer from server
        throw new IOException();
    }
    else {
        return answer;
    }

}

private String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = null;
    try{
     s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\r\n");}
    catch (Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

}

Comment: The isConnected() test is pointless. If the socket wasn't connected you wouldn't have a socket. It doesn't tell you the current state of the connection.

Answer (score 3):

I can only see one client-side that *might* cause this ... and I'm doubtful about it.  (That is to say: try this, just in case it makes a differences, but I don't think it will.)

```
  this.out.write(message.getBytes());
  Log.d("SOCKET","WRITING COMPLETE. " + message);
```

The potential problem is that if `out` is a "buffered" stream, then a `write` may only result in the bytes being written to the buffer.  It may be necessary to call `this.out.flush()` to "push" to the server.

But I am doubtful it will help, because (to my knowledge) a socket output stream isn't buffered in Java.  I think it is more likely that the real problem is on the server side.

If you are stumped with figuring out which side the problem is occuring, I suggest you try using a network monitoring / packet sniffing tool (on the server side) to check if the data is reaching the server host.

---

While I have your attention, your exception code is really, really bad.

1. Don't declare methods as `throws Throwable` (or `throws Exception`).  That basically says "this method may throw **ANY** exception, and I'm not telling you which one".  When you do that, the caller code has to *cope with* any exception, which is basically impossible to do intelligently.

   What you *should* do is to declare the method as throwing the *checked* exceptions that the code *can* throw.  For example, in your case, `IOException` is probably sufficient.
2. It is not a good idea to catch an exception, log it, and then rethrow it.  Why?  Because further up the stack there are probably other methods that will see the exception.  They can't know if the exception has already been logged or not.  So should they log it (possibly resulting in duplicate logs events for the same problem) or not (possibly resulting in the exception going unlogged.)
3. Don't throw exceptions without a message:

   ```
         throw new IOException();
   ```

   It is lazy.  You should always include a simple message that can (at least) be grep'd or googled for.

In addition, your testing of `Socket.isConnected()` all over the place is unnecessary.  According to the javadoc:

> Returns: true if the socket was successfuly connected to a server
>
> Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means
>   this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if
>   it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.

So repeatedly testing `isConnected` is nugatory.  If it returns `true` once, it will will always return `true` from then on.

Even the initial `isConnected` test in `setStreams` is doubtful.  I'd just call `getInputStream` without testing, and rely on the `Socket` API throwing an `IOException` if the socket is in the wrong state.

Comment: The confusion with isConnected() is that people use it to test the state of the connection, when it only indicates the state of the Socket. It doesn't change value when the peer disconnects.

Comment: I fixed the code by your advice, and checked the network traffic with wireshark. On the port my app, and server work no packets were caugth. I also tried with this.out.flush(), didn't help. Is there anything obvious that im missing?

Comment: @Talkopel - At this point, I'm starting to suspect strange network shenanigans.  Perhaps you should write an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and post it on Github or somewhere so that people can look at it, run it etc.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively reading lines with that obscure Scanner usage, but you're not writing lines. So the scanner will block until a line terminator or EOS arrives.

You need to append a line terminator when sending.

Comment: +1 - Yes, this is plausible.  Especially if this code (or similar) is used on *both* sides.

Comment: It is terminated on both sides with an EOL.